# SVN changes in imported files to working copy

Tags: svn, version-control

I have create a svn repository and imported a folder into my svn repository using

```
svnadmin create repo
svn mkdir trunk -m "drunk"
svn import /home/my/folder file://home/my/svn/repo/trunk
```

i rsync the "/home/my/folder" from some other place everyday,

Also i had create a working copy on other machine using

```
svn co svn://myhost/repo
```

But when i do a svn update on my working copy, i dont get the rsynced changes from /home/my/folder. How do i correct this?

Comment: Are you committing the changes after the rsync? Otherwise there is nothing to update.

Comment: no i am not doing that, i am assuming if my svn repo refers to that directory it should keep track of all changes to that directory?

Comment: See my answer. You need to make /home/my/folder a working copy after the import (delete contents and do a checkout), and then do commits after every rsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.import) does not create a working copy.

You need to make a working copy by doing a checkout on the machine that is going to get the rsync updates.

You also need to do a commit to that working copy after the rsync completes, otherwise your repository is not going to be updated and doing an update on another machine will not get anything.

Comment: just curious, isnt it really weird of svn that when i do a svn co for the first time, it gets the imported files ( no co and commit ) also in the working copy?

Comment: When you import, you put a copy into the repository. So doing a co at another location will get *that* copy. Until you make commits to any working copy, the repository will not be updated.

Comment: Also why dont i see the imported files in my repository using ls in the trunk dir?

Comment: hey it would be really healpful for every svn noob if you could write down the instructions for achieveing this. :) thanks

Comment: Click the svn import link above in my answer. It goes to the svn book. Very good documentation for using svn.

Answer (score 1):

First: Don't mix `file://` with `svn://`. Use the same protocol on both systems even if the file is local to your system. Otherwise, you might accidentally change the permissions on the files and folders inside the Subversion repository which would cause havoc for everyone else.

When you import a directory (like you did), that directory doesn't become a Subversion working directory. You'll have to do a checkout to create a working directory and use that in Subversion.

I hope I am understanding your question correctly.

The working copy on the other system is showing the files you added. Is that correct?

Comment: i think i did not explain it correctly, i am hosting a svn repo on the first machine using svnserve.

Comment: You are talking about two repos? Or, is your repos on the first machine, and you access it on the second machine via the `svn://` protocol. If you can do that, you have `svnserve` running on the **first** machine, so you can use the `svn://` protocol on it too.